# How can I put a long html code inside a variable without taking too much time to escape it

Tags: html

So I have a lot of embed html code like this one :

```
<iframe src="http://www.mysite.com/embed/2049340993" frameborder="0" width="608" height="468" scrolling="no"><a href="http://www.mysite.com/view_video.php?viewkey=2049340993">
```

I want to put them in differents variables however I must escape all characters like this :

```
var embedSource = "<iframe src=\"http://www.mysite.com/embed/2049340993\" frameborder=\"0\" width=\"608\" height=\"468\" scrolling=\"no\"><a href=\"http://www.mysite.com/view_video.php?viewkey=2049340993\">";
```

Is there any faster way to achieve this ?

Comment: If all you need to do is escape the `"` (double quotes), something like `embedSource = embedSource.Replace("\"", "\\\");` should work.

Comment: I think you need an extra " at the end.

Comment: C# and asp-classic tags - Which one is wrong? (answers imply ASP.Net, if you really into original ASP please tag language appropriately).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use apostrophe (single quote) in the HTML. this way you won't have to escape it.

Comment: I would rather use the single quote in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

I would [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) the quotes with apostrophes.

```
embedSource = embedSource.Replace("\"", "'");
```

or, if necessary,

```
embedSource = embedSource.Replace("\"", "\'");
```

In JavaScript `replace()` has a lowercase **r**.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is don't put double quotes

```
var embedSource = "<iframe src='http://www.mysite.com/embed/2049340993' frameborder='0' width='608' height='468' scrolling='no'><a href='http://www.mysite.com/view_video.php?viewkey=2049340993'>";
```